# Loop Through Pattern Of Characters and Print Out Corresponding Text

Tags: python

Hi working on a sort of morse-code problem where a user would input a string in a  format like this

```
pattern = ['.', '.', '_', '.', '_', '.']
```

and the code would print out the resulting word for each like so:

```
"dot-dot-dash-dot-dash-dot"
```

I've tried this:

```
def ss(pattern):
    dotdash = ""
    for s in pattern:
        if s == ".":
            dotdash+=("dot")
        elif s == "_":
            dotdash+=("dash")
    x = "-".join(dotdash)
    print(x)

ss(['.', '.', '_', '.', '_', '.'])
```

but that's just giving me output like this:

```
d-o-t-d-o-t-d-a-s-h-d-o-t-d-a-s-h-d-o-t
```

looking for a solution to separate those dots and dashes with a hyphen--just a bit stumped.  thinking maybe to split--based on the words--but just unsure how to accomplish that. any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you are passing to the `join()` function is a string, so it will iterate through every letter in the string, that's why you are getting this output. What you really want to do is use a list, so that `join()` iterates through every word in the list:

```
...
dotdash = []
for s in pattern:
    if s == ".":
        dotdash.append("dot")
    elif s == "_":
        dotdash.append("dash")
x = "-".join(dotdash)
...
```

Comment: yep just figured that out thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2):

You could add the hyphens first with `join`, which gives you a string, and then apply two replacements to get the final string:

```
def ss(pattern):
    return '-'.join(pattern).replace('.', 'dot').replace('_', 'dash')

print(ss(['.', '.', '_', '.', '_', '.'])) // dot-dot-dash-dot-dash-dot
```

Answer (score 0):

well, i'll just go ahead and respond to my own answer--woops.  Easy solution here--i just changed dotdash to a list, and that took care of all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Change ("dot") to ("dot",) with a trailing comma, and do the same for ("dash").
The trailing comma forces it to be a list type.

Edit: Also, change dotdash to be initialised like dotdash = []